# How to simplify object mapping in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am currently using the following code, to pickup some properties from `action.payload` and assign to object `weather`.

I would like to know if there is a more elegant and concise way to do the same operation in ES6.

```
let weather = {}
weather.name = action.payload.name
weather.country = action.payload.sys.country
weather.temperature = action.payload.main.temp
weather.temperatureMin = action.payload.main.temp_min
weather.temperatureMax = action.payload.main.temp_max
weather.weatherMain = action.payload.weather[0].main
weather.weatherDescription = action.payload.weather[0].description
weather.weatherIcon = action.payload.weather[0].icon
weather.updatedTime = new Date().toString()
weather.windDegree = action.payload.wind.deg
weather.windSpeed = action.payload.wind.speed
weather.visibility = action.payload.visibility
```

Comment: maybe object spread syntax in next version of js? I am using babel.

Comment: Is `weather` an array or an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no particular language-level magic here. You are pulling from multiple levels of the `action` object, and renaming many properties on the fly. If the names were remaining constant, object destructuring and structuring assignments might solve the problem outright. But as it stands, about the greatest clarity you can get is by not duplicating so many names. E.g.:

```
let payload = action.payload
let weather = {
  name:           payload.name,
  country:        payload.sys.country,
  temperature:    payload.main.temp,
  temperatureMin: payload.main.temp_min,
  temperatureMax: payload.main.temp_max,
  weatherMain:    payload.weather[0].main,
  weatherDescription: payload.weather[0].description,
  weatherIcon:    payload.weather[0].icon,
  updatedTime:    new Date().toString(),
  windDegree:     payload.wind.deg,
  windSpeed:      payload.wind.speed,
  visibility:     payload.visibility
}
```

It is certainly possible to use more ES2015 destructuring features as part of this assignment. For example:

```
const { payload } = action
const { main, weather, wind, sys } = payload
let weather = {
  name:           payload.name,
  country:        sys.country,
  temperature:    main.temp,
  temperatureMin: main.temp_min,
  temperatureMax: main.temp_max,
  weatherMain:    weather[0].main,
  weatherDescription: weather[0].description,
  weatherIcon:    weather[0].icon,
  updatedTime:    new Date().toString(),
  windDegree:     wind.deg,
  windSpeed:      wind.speed,
  visibility:     payload.visibility
}
```

I do *not* generally recommend this further step. To my thinking, this doesn't necessarily make things clearer. At least, there are trade-offs to consider. The natural correspondence between the original object and its multiple levels of structure becomes more hidden; one needs to remember and interpret the origins of sub-objects like `wind`, `weather`, `main`, and `sys`. But on the plus side it's both more concise and more aggressive in ES2015 use. You'll have to judge whether this is better or just fancier.

Answer (score 1):

You could do for example object destructuring, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Operatory/Destructuring_assignment). Less writing.

```
const { payload } = action;

let weather = {
  name : payload.name,
  country: payload.sys.country
  ...
}
```

you can destructure object properties even more like so:

```
const { payload : { name, weather, wind } } = action;
```

See working example:

```js
const action = {
  payload : {
    name: 'John',
    sys: {
      country: 'USA'
    },
    main: {
      temp_min: 0,
      temp_max: 30
    },
   weather : [
      {
        main: 'test',
      description: 'long description',
      icon : 'icon-weather'
      },
      {
        main: 'test2',
      description: 'long description2',
      icon : 'icon-weather'
      }
   ],
   wind : {
     deg: 123,
     speed: 123
   },
   visibility : 'ok',
    date: new Date().toString()
  }
}

const { payload : { name, weather, wind } } = action;

console.log(name, weather, wind);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) can help you.

```js
// Example action.
const action = {
  payload: {
   name: 'lorem',
    sys: {
     country: 'ipsum'
   },
   main: {
      temp: '30',
      temp_min: '15',
      temp_max: '30'
    },
   weather: [
      {
       main: {
          temp: '50',
          temp_min: '15',
         temp_max: '60'
        },
        description: 'lorem ipsum',
       icon: 'test.ico'
      }
    ],
   wind: {
      deg: '30',
      speed: '180'
    },
   visibility: '20'
  },
  // ...
}

// User provided function.
const makeWeatherOriginal = (action) => {
  let weather = {}
  weather.name = action.payload.name
  weather.country = action.payload.sys.country
  weather.temperature = action.payload.main.temp
  weather.temperatureMin = action.payload.main.temp_min
  weather.temperatureMax = action.payload.main.temp_max
  weather.weatherMain = action.payload.weather[0].main
  weather.weatherDescription = action.payload.weather[0].description
  weather.weatherIcon = action.payload.weather[0].icon
  weather.updatedTime = new Date().toString()
  weather.windDegree = action.payload.wind.deg
  weather.windSpeed = action.payload.wind.speed
  weather.visibility = action.payload.visibility
  return weather
}

// Example function using ES2015 object destructuring.
const makeWeather = (action) => {
// Object destructuring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring
  const {
    payload: {
      name,
      sys: {
        country
      },
      main: {
        temp,
        temp_min,
        temp_max
      },
      weather,
      wind: {
        deg,
        speed
      },
      visibility
    }
  } = action

  const computedWeather = {
    name,
    country,
    temperature: temp,
    temperatureMin: temp_min,
    temperatureMax: temp_max,
    weatherMain: weather[0].main,
    weatherDescription: weather[0].description,
    weatherIcon: weather[0].icon,
    updatedTime: new Date().toString(),
    windDegree: deg,
    windSpeed: speed,
    visibility
  }
  return computedWeather
}

const computedOne = makeWeather(action)
const computedTwo = makeWeatherOriginal(action)
const computedOneJson = JSON.stringify(computedOne)
const computedTwoJson = JSON.stringify(computedTwo)

if(computedOneJson === computedTwoJson) {
document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = "Success.";
}
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about ES6, you can use `Proxy` to proxy through object properties.

Example for playing with it: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/y19rz7fj/1/

Create a mapping of desired props to source props:

```
const mapProps = {
  name:           'name',
  country:        'sys.country',
  temperature:    'main.temp',
  temperatureMin: 'main.temp_min',
  visibility:     'visibility'
}
```

Then define a proxy handler:

```
const handler = {
    get: function(t, p) {
    const newKey = mapProps[p];
    const levels = newKey.split('.');
    return (levels.length > 1) 
        ? levels.reduce((o, c) => o[c], t)
        : t[newKey]
  }
}
```

Assuming your source object looks like this:

```
const source = {
    name: 'Name',
  sys: {
    country: 'AU'
  },
  main: {
    temp: '34',
    temp_min: '13'
  },
  visibility: '35%'
}
```

You can create a `proxy` object like this:

```
const newObj = new Proxy(source, handler)
```

Now you can access your properties like this:

```
newObj.temperatureMin // returns 13 (>>source.main.temp_min)
```

Things to do: expand `handler` to deal with `[]` notations and handle object methods.

Full example:

```js
const source = {
 name: 'Name',
  sys: {
   country: 'AU'
  },
  main: {
   temp: '34',
    temp_min: '13'
  },
  visibility: '35%'
}

const mapProps = {
  name:           'name',
  country:        'sys.country',
  temperature:    'main.temp',
  temperatureMin: 'main.temp_min',
  visibility:     'visibility'
}

const handler = {
 get: function(t, p) {
   const newKey = mapProps[p];
    const levels = newKey.split('.');
    return (levels.length > 1) 
     ? levels.reduce((o, c) => o[c], t)
   : t[newKey]
  }
}

const proxy = new Proxy(source, handler)

for (let k in mapProps) {
 console.log( proxy[k] )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring assignment as an expression, or define a function to pass the object to, to avoid declaring variables globally, return object from function.

```js
const o = {action:
            {payload:
              {name:1
              , sys:{country:2}
              , main:{temp:3,temp_min:4, temp_max:5}
              , weather:[{main:6, description:7, icon:8}]
              , wind:{speed:9, deg:10}
              , visibility:11}
            }
          };

let weather = {};
{
  const w = weather;
  (
    {name: w.name
    , sys: {country: w.country}
    , main: {temp: w.temperature, temp_min: w.temperatureMin, temp_max: w.temperatureMax}
    , weather: [{main: w.weatherMain, description: w.weatherDescription, icon: w.weatherIcon}]
    , updateTime: w.updateTime = new Date().toString()
    , wind: {deg: w.windDegree, speed: w.windSpeed}
    , visibility: w.visibility
    } = o.action.payload
  );
}
console.log(weather);
```